# Deleting rows when meeting a specific condition when in a range in SAS

Tags: datetime, select, sas, where-clause

I need help with the following dataset:

```
ID   Code  SAStime
001  1     0
001  1     600
001  1     1200
...  ...   ...
001  1     84600
001  2     85200
001  2     85800
```

I would like to be able to tell the program, that if Code=1 between SAStime 0 and 85800 then to delete those row of data. So I have something left, like this:

```
ID   Code  SAStime
001  2     85200
001  2     85800
```

I've tried with drop, keep and where functions but for some reason it's not working.

Comment: Can you show your example code with `where`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are asking about SAS grammar, you can learn it from .
As for this question, the anwser is below:

```
data have;
    input ID$ Code SAStime;
    cards;
001  1     0
001  1     600
001  1     1200
001  1     84600
001  2     85200
001  2     85800
;
run;

data want;
    set have;
    if Code = 1 and 0 <= SAStime <= 85800 then delete;
run;
```

Comment: Per SO guidelines you should add some explanation to your answer but it's technically correct.

Comment: I agree with you, @Reeza, I was a little anxious.

Comment: I was not using = for neither of the values for SAStime, that's why I was not getting it back as I wanted. Thanks for the help!